# How to make a UILabel clickable?

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, uitapgesturerecognizer

I would like to make a UILabel clickable.

I have tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
class DetailViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var tripDetails: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        ...
        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("tapFunction:"))
        tripDetails.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    }

    func tapFunction(sender:UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        print("tap working")
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the frame of your `UILabel`?  Are you sure you're touching in the label's frame?  Do you have an `UIViews` covering the label?  Is `userInteractionEnabled` set to `True` for the label?

Comment: Make sure your UILabel IBOutlet is hooked up from your Nib or Storyboard

Answer (score 209, accepted):

Have you tried to set `isUserInteractionEnabled` to `true` on the `tripDetails` label? This should work.

Comment: thanks for the answer!!! Here I have another issue still about UITapGestureRecognizer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33659078/swift-how-to-make-a-uiview-clickable-in-uitableviewcell

Comment: I am trying to change background color on tap but the tap event is firing when i release my finger. Is there a way to catch touch down event? Long press is not what i am looking for.

Comment: oh, wow so label by default is not user interact-able, appreciate it!

Answer (score 132):

**Swift 3 Update**

Replace

```
Selector("tapFunction:")
```

with

```
#selector(DetailViewController.tapFunction)
```

Example:

```
class DetailViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var tripDetails: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        ...

        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(DetailViewController.tapFunction))
        tripDetails.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        tripDetails.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    }

    @objc
    func tapFunction(sender:UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        print("tap working")
    }
}
```

Comment: I had to annotate the tap function with `@objc`.

Answer (score 54):

**SWIFT 4  Update**

```
 @IBOutlet weak var tripDetails: UILabel!

 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(GameViewController.tapFunction))
    tripDetails.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    tripDetails.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
}

@objc func tapFunction(sender:UITapGestureRecognizer) {

    print("tap working")
}
```

Answer (score 31):

**Swift 5**

Similar to @liorco, but need to replace **@objc** with **@IBAction**.

```
class DetailViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var tripDetails: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        ...

        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(DetailViewController.tapFunction))
        tripDetails.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        tripDetails.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    }

    @IBAction func tapFunction(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        print("tap working")
    }
}
```

This is working on Xcode 10.2.

Comment: `@IBAction` is only needed to expose method to Xcode's Interface Builder (hence IB). It also acts as `@objc` but if you add the gestures or other actions with code you should use the `@objc` annotation

Answer (score 16):

**Swift 3 Update**

```
yourLabel.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
```

Comment: this didn't help me. I am trying to do it on a label in a tableview

Comment: made it working here as well, even if it was already set in the Storyboard.

Answer (score 16):

Good and convenient solution:

In your ViewController:

```
@IBOutlet weak var label: LabelButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.label.onClick = {
        // TODO
    }
}
```

You can place this in your ViewController or in another .swift file(e.g. CustomView.swift):

```
@IBDesignable class LabelButton: UILabel {
    var onClick: () -> Void = {}
    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        onClick()
    }
}
```

In Storyboard select Label and on right pane in "Identity Inspector" in field class select LabelButton.

**Don't forget to enable in Label Attribute Inspector "User Interaction Enabled"**

Comment: Inside viewDidLoad() need to add this line if doesn't work:  self.label.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

Answer (score 4):

You need to enable the user interaction of that label.....

**For e.g**

`yourLabel.userInteractionEnabled = true`

Comment: this didn't help me. I am trying to do it on a label in a tableview

Answer (score 3):

For swift 3.0 You can also change gesture long press time duration

```
label.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
let longPress:UILongPressGestureRecognizer = UILongPressGestureRecognizer.init(target: self, action: #selector(userDragged(gesture:))) 
longPress.minimumPressDuration = 0.2
label.addGestureRecognizer(longPress)
```

Answer (score 3):

Pretty easy to overlook like I did, but don't forget to use `UITapGestureRecognizer` rather than `UIGestureRecognizer`.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks [researcher](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4545795/researcher)

Here's my solution for programmatic user interface using UIKit.

I've tried it only on **Swift 5**. And It worked.

Fun fact is you don't have to set `isUserInteractionEnabled = true` explicitly.

```
import UIKit

open class LabelButon: UILabel {
    var onClick: () -> Void = {}
    
    public override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    }
    
    public required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
    }
    
    public convenience init() {
        self.init(frame: .zero)
    }
    
    open override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        onClick()
    }
}
```

Uses:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    let label = LabelButton()
    label.text = "Label"
    label.onClick = {
        // TODO
    }
}
```

> **Don't forget to set constraints. Otherwise it won't appear on view.**

Answer (score 0):

On top of all of the other answers, this depends on where the label is, it might be behind some subviews. You might think you tap on the label but maybe click the top view. To solve this you can bring the label view to the front with the following line.

```
self.view.bringSubviewToFront(lblView)
```

Answer (score -4):

As described in the above solution
you should enable the user interaction first and add the tap gesture

this code has been tested using

## Swift4 - Xcode 9.2

```
yourlabel.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
yourlabel.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(){
                //TODO 
            })
```

Comment: I get `Cannot invoke initializer for type 'UITapGestureRecognizer' with an argument list of type '(() -> Void)'` when I try this.