# iOS - Replace a label by a button

Tags: ios, interface-builder

I've added a label in a view controller via the interface builder, and I've added a lot of constraints to it, but I want to replace it by a button. Can I accomplish this without losing all the constraints ? Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you can save your constraints inside interface builder. However, you can add a tap gesture recognizer to make the label perform an action when it is tapped (act like a button).

This code can help you get started:

```
let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTap(_ :)))
myLabel.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
myLabel.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)


func handleTap(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    // perform some action when the label is tapped
}
```

You can look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33658521/swift-how-to-make-a-uilabel-clickable) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Don’t replace by button

Add tap gesture for click action

Answer (score -1):

you don't need to remove that label. Just addGestureRecognizer a tap gesture on label.

```
let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTap(_ :)))
myLabel.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
myLabel.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)


func handleTap(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    // perform some action when the label is tapped
}
```

Comment: Why would you copy and paste another users answer? That contributes nothing.