# How to detect anchor tag link click in NSAttributedString created from html string

Tags: ios, swift, nsattributedstring

I am creating NSAttributedString by using html:

```
let htmlString = "<body style='padding-left:50px'><h1>Hello World</h1><div><a href=https://apple.com/offer/samsung-faq/>Click Here</a></div><p>This is a sample text</p><pre>This is also sample pre text</pre></body>"
```

And here i am setting it to UILabel by using extension method

```
someLabel.attributedText = htmlString.htmlToAttributedString
```

NSAttributedString Extension:

```
extension String {
    var htmlToAttributedString: NSAttributedString? {
        guard let data = data(using: .utf8) else { return NSAttributedString() }
        do {
            return try NSAttributedString(data: data, options: [NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey.documentType:  NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html], documentAttributes: nil)
        } catch {
            return NSAttributedString()
        }
    }
}
```

Here i want an callback method to detect link which is there in html string as anchor tag.
How will i get an event on click and how can i get the url in that event callback ?

Please help...

Comment: Have you reviewed this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33658521/how-to-make-a-uilabel-clickable

Comment: Don't use `UILabel` for that, use `UITextView`, that's what it's made for. See this session of WWDC (at ~2:40): https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/221/ `UILabel` aren't made for "click ability", they are here for displaying text, that's all.

Comment: You can use `UITextView` and it has a delegate called `shouldInteractWith`, in which you can get the link.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `UITextView` instead of `UILabel` and it has a property to convert your text to hyperlink.

You will have to make your `UIViewController` confirm to `UITextViewDelegate` protocol and implement `textView(_:shouldInteractWith:in:interaction:`. your standard `UITextView` setup should look something like this, don't forget the `delegate` and `dataDetectorTypes`.

```
@IBOutlet weak var txtView: UITextView!
// make IBOutlet of UITextView

txtTest.delegate = self
txtTest.isUserInteractionEnabled = true // default: true
txtTest.isEditable = false // default: true
txtTest.isSelectable = true // default: true
txtTest.dataDetectorTypes = [.link]
```

`UITextViewDelegate` method `shouldInteractWithURL`:

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWith URL: URL, in characterRange: NSRange, interaction: UITextItemInteraction) -> Bool {
    print("Link Selected!")
    return true
}
```

`HTML` to `NSAttributedString` Extension:

```
extension String{
    func convertHtml() -> NSAttributedString{
        guard let data = data(using: .utf8) else { return NSAttributedString() }
        do{
            return try NSAttributedString(data: data, options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType, NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue], documentAttributes: nil)
        }catch{
            return NSAttributedString()
        }
    }
}
```

then you can use it like so.

```
let htmlString = "<body style='padding-left:50px'><h1>Hello World</h1><div><a href=https://apple.com/offer/samsung-faq/>Click Here</a></div><p>This is a sample text</p><pre>This is also sample pre text</pre></body>"

txtTest.attributedText = htmlString.convertHtml()
```