# Detect Link in Label

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm inserting some data to my `Label` in xcode.

It contains html `< a href="">` tags. I would like to make this link clickable.

I tried to use `UITextView` and in storyboard set `Link` check to detect links. But in my case I have the link inside my text.

So I'm unable to do something like this:

```swift
attributedString.addAttribute(.link,
                                      value: "https://www.google.co.jp/",
                                      range: NSString(string: baseString).range(of: "here"))
```

Because my data are like

```swift
print(data)

>>> "<a href="www.google.com">here</a>"
```

how could I handle this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50969015/how-to-detect-anchor-tag-link-click-in-nsattributedstring-created-from-html-stri