# How to click UITabBarItem and show new ViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, uistoryboard, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

I add a tab bar to view controller manually, this is not a `tabBarController`, because I only want the tab bar UI, not the tab bar function

I want to click on tab bar and show new `ViewController`, but I cannot do that in `storyBoard`

[image]
[image]
[image]

If I use this method, xcode prompt me `Value of type 'UITabBarItem' has no member 'isUserInteractionEnabled'` and `Value of type 'UITabBarItem' has no member 'addGestureRecognizer'`

How can I click a UITabBarItem?

[How to make a UILabel clickable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33658521/how-to-make-a-uilabel-clickable)

```
@IBOutlet weak var setting: UITabBarItem!
@IBOutlet weak var activity: UITabBarItem!
@IBOutlet weak var profile: UITabBarItem!
@IBOutlet weak var connect: UITabBarItem!
@IBOutlet weak var scanner: UITabBarItem!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapFunction))
    setting.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    setting.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

    activity.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    activity.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

    profile.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    profile.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

    connect.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    connect.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

    scanner.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    scanner.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
}
@objc func tapFunction(sender:UITapGestureRecognizer) {

    print("tap working")
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Value of type 'UITabBarItem' has no member 'isUserInteractionEnabled' and Value of type 'UITabBarItem' has no member 'addGestureRecognizer'

Because of UITabBarItem inherits from UIBarItem, that inherits from NSObject, not UIView

> For enable/disable the `UITabBarItem`, you can using the `isEnabled` property

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibaritem/1616418-isenabled?changes=_2

> For catch the action of `UITabBarItem`, you can catch it in the UITabBar's delegate `tabbar:didselectitem`

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitabbardelegate/1623463-tabbar?changes=_2

and got the item's position via `UITabBarItem.tag`
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibaritem/1616419-tag?changes=_2

Comment: I print item tag in `didSelect`, all tag is 0

Comment: @CLSo : did you set the tag for UITabbarItem? In storyboard or in code by `UITabbarItem.tag = tag_index`

Comment: I see, now is ok