# UILabel set onClick

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

I'm building an application in Swift 3, so I want to call a function if I click on a particular UILabel, so I'm write this code but not works:

```
let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.tapFunction))
    self.labelTemp.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    self.labelTemp.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
```

How can I render UILabel clickable ?

Comment: You just need to defined the function you passed to `selector`. In your `ViewController` class just write `func tapFunction { }` and it will be call.

Comment: @bircastri add "tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1" to recognize tab

Comment: is your label visible on screen?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33658521/how-to-make-a-uilabel-clickable

Answer (score 2):

Set user interaction enabled for the UILabel and add the below code in the `viewDidLoad()`

```
self.label.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.labelTapped))
self.label.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
```

Add the tap action function as below :

```
@objc func labelTapped(_ gestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    print("Label clicked")
}
```

Please make user that there is no other transparent view overlapping the UILabel in the view. If the UILabel is a part of another view then please make sure that the container View's user interaction is enabled.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your selector should be an `@objc func` within `self`.

`<#YourLabel#>.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.handleLabelTap)))`

And when the user taps the label it will trigger:

```swift
@objc func handleLabelTap() {
    // handle label tap here    
}
```

Comment: not works, I'm try to copy your code but it not works

Comment: did you enable `isUserInteractionEnabled`?

Comment: this is the standard way of adding `UITapGestureRecognizer`, make sure there is nothing in front of your label and you're tapping inside the label bounds.

Comment: otherwise the problem is somewhere else, not on the "onClick"

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure that You have connected the outlet to `UILabel` because I have created simple demo code by copy-paste your code and it is worked as expected.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapFunction))
    self.labelTemp.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    self.labelTemp.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
}

@objc func tapFunction() {
    print("tapFunction")
}
```

**I suggest, Please remove `UILabel` from `UIViewController` and add it again.**

[Download sample code](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1bkI7NjXi3I5xa8uTe9n6xWHp8OR2bLqL)

**Note: - Please ensure that user-interaction of `UILabel`is enabled**

Answer (score 0):

You are lacking a function to trigger when the gesture touch is recognized. You need to add following:

```
let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapFunction(_:)))
    self.labelTemp.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    self.labelTemp.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

@objc func tapFunction(_ gestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    // handle label tap here    
}
```

Comment: I have updated my answer please check it if it works.

Answer (score 0):

1. First you need to add Tap Gesture into storyboard [image]
2. Create Action of that particular gesture

   override func viewDidLoad() {

   ```
           super.viewDidLoad()

           let tapOnLabel = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.tapGestireAction))
           self.labelTemp.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
           self.labelTemp.addGestureRecognizer(tapOnLabel)
       }


     @IBAction func tapGestureAction(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

           //Perform action
       }
   ```