# How to show another View controller when a label is clicked

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, uilabel

Juts like clicking a button to show another view contoller, is there a way to do that with a label?

Comment: add a `UITapGestureRecognizer`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a UILabel clickable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33658521/how-to-make-a-uilabel-clickable)

Comment: where should I add this? how does this work?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Is there any specific reason?

Comment: I have a label with fontawesome icons, the icons didn't work with the button (If you know how fontawesome works) so I need to do it with a label.

Comment: @AmedLMAB Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/47176926/8014650

Answer (score 0):

**Call below function**

**NOTE: Please set identifier same which you are you in below code**

```
class firstViewController: UIViewController {

   @IBOutlet weak var yourlabel: UILabel

   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()

       self.addGesture()
   }

   func addGesture() {

       let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self. labelTapped(_:)))
       tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
       self.yourlabel.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
       self.yourlabel.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
   }

   @objc
   func labelTapped(_ tap: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

        let storyboard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let SecondVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondViewController") as! SecondViewController
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(SecondVC, animated: animated)
   }
}
```

**Second ViewController**

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

  override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
  }
}
```

Comment: which code does connect my label to another view controller? what should I write in the action area to do that?

Comment: in firstViewController labelTapped() method called when you tap on label(addGesture() method must be implemented).
and function will navigate to secondViewController. (NOTE* UIavigationController is must be rootviewcontrooler)