# How to set action in label?

Tags: ios, swift, toast

Here is my code:

added gesture in viewDidLoad

```
let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapLabel(tap:)))
            toastLabel.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
            toastLabel.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

func showLongToast( message: String) {        
    toastLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: controller.view.frame.origin.x + 20, y: controller.view.frame.size.height-200, width: controller.view.frame.size.width - 40, height: 125))
    toastLabel.numberOfLines = 0
    toastLabel.textAlignment = .center
    toastLabel.contentMode = .center
    toastLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0.7)
    toastLabel.textColor = UIColor(red: 74/255, green: 74/255, blue: 74/255, alpha: 1)
    toastLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Montserrat-Medium", size: 15.0)
    let trimmedString = message.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
    let string = NSMutableAttributedString(string: trimmedString)
    string.setColorForText("Enter Manually", with: #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 0.4196078431, blue: 0.1812392979, alpha: 1))
    toastLabel.attributedText = string
    toastLabel.layer.cornerRadius = 25
    toastLabel.clipsToBounds = true
    controller.view.addSubview(toastLabel)
    controller.view.bringSubviewToFront(toastLabel)
  }
```

I have call the function from viewController :

```
showLongToast(message: "Please Hold the lens or choose you can Enter Manually.", controller: self)
```

But toast message could not set action anymore? Have any idea
please post in comment. Thanks.

Comment: You created a gesture recognizer, did you add it to the label with `label.addGestureRecognizer()`?

Comment: add your UITapGestureRecognizer inside the scope of showLongToast

Comment: Your code is working fine for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a UILabel clickable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33658521/how-to-make-a-uilabel-clickable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding the `tap` gesture recognizer to `toastLabel` in `viewDidLoad()`, but then you are creating a ***new*** `UILabel` inside `showLongToast()`

Change:

```
toastLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: controller.view.frame.origin.x + 20, y: controller.view.frame.size.height-200, width: controller.view.frame.size.width - 40, height: 125))
```

in `showLongToast()` to:

```
toastLabel.frame = CGRect(x: controller.view.frame.origin.x + 20, y: controller.view.frame.size.height-200, width: controller.view.frame.size.width - 40, height: 125)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how your `viewDidLoad()` and  `tapLabel(tap:)` should look like,

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.showLongToast(message: "Please Hold the lens or choose you can Enter Manually.", controller: self)
    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapLabel(tap:)))
    toastLabel.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    toastLabel.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
}

@objc func tapLabel(tap: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    print("tapped..!!!")
}
```

And the signature of `showLongToast` won't compile with your code. It should be like,

```
func showLongToast( message: String, controller: UIViewController) {
    //your code here...
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapLabel(tap:)))
    toastLabel.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    toastLabel.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    }    
    func showLongToast( message: String) {        
        toastLabel.frame = CGRect(x: controller.view.frame.origin.x + 20, y: controller.view.frame.size.height-200, width: controller.view.frame.size.width - 40, height: 125)
        toastLabel.numberOfLines = 0
        toastLabel.textAlignment = .center
        toastLabel.contentMode = .center
        toastLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0.7)
        toastLabel.textColor = UIColor(red: 74/255, green: 74/255, blue: 74/255, alpha: 1)
        toastLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Montserrat-Medium", size: 15.0)
        let trimmedString = message.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
        let string = NSMutableAttributedString(string: trimmedString)
        string.setColorForText("Enter Manually", with: #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 0.4196078431, blue: 0.1812392979, alpha: 1))
        toastLabel.attributedText = string
        toastLabel.layer.cornerRadius = 25
        toastLabel.clipsToBounds = true
        controller.view.addSubview(toastLabel)
        controller.view.bringSubviewToFront(toastLabel)
}
```

Comment: Please add an explanation why you think your code answers the question.